# If Portfolio item has tag, add CSS

Tags: php, css

I've recently purchased the Stockholm theme and am trying to customize it:

I would like to have the ability to mark certain Portfolio Items as being 'SOLD' with black squares in the top-left corner, as can be done with Products with 'SALE' blocks. An example is found [here, under "latest items"](http://demo.select-themes.com/stockholm11/). I want to be able to achieve the same effect with portfolio items like the 3 images above "latest items".

I imagine that a good way to go about this would be to say that:

> "if portfolio item has a ***Sold*** tag, add the following CSS".

And then use the following CSS:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-weight: 700;
background-color: #393939;
color: #fff;
z-index: 100;
```

But that's as much as I can figure out. In which php file should I write this *"if portfolio item has 'Sold' tag"* rule? And how would I write it?

Comment: _In which php file should I write this_ in the file you produce the view.

Comment: @Chay22 I'm not sure what you mean... I appreciate the reply. Would it be the [shortcodes.php file](http://prnt.sc/aydsj7)?

Answer (score 0):

You can check with tag in below given fashion. You can use below code inside your post loop. If you don't know where is your desired post loop, you can provide your code or directory files so that I can provide you exact code to work with.

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
foreach($posttags as $tag) {
if($tag->name == 'Sold') {?>
 //here you will add your styles what so ever
<?php }
}
}
?>
```

Hope, that makes sense, for further reading https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags

Comment: Would it be in the shortcodes.php file? perhaps somewhere here:

`/* Portfolio list shortcode */

if (!function_exists('portfolio_list')) {

 function portfolio_list($atts, $content = null) {

  global $wp_query;
  global $qode_options;`

Comment: if at some point you come back, please do reply, I'll keep checking back.

Answer (score 0):

In yout php file, you need to detect if portfolio has "Sold" property.
I don't have access to your PHP back-end, so I'will try to simulate.

When you show your html, you could add a new class, something like:

```
<li class="... <?php if($portfolio->isSold){ echo " sold";}?>"> ...
```

and in your css try to put this:

```
.sold {
    background-color: #e6ae48;
}
```